# UITextfield won't let me type

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, interface-builder

I have a UITextfield in my application, which I added though `Interface Builder`. However, when I run simulator and try to fill in text, nothing happens. I can tap it, and it'll become selected (flashing blue line) but when I type the placeholder just stays in place and no text appears.

Is this perhaps a bug, or Is there a solution to said problem?

-- Edit --

I had hardware keyboard connected from the beginning

Comment: Is your hardware keyboard connected? If not, navigate to **Hardware/Keyboard** and select **Connect Hardware Keyboard**.

Comment: i guess your hardware keyboard might not have connected . use Cmd+Shft+K .

Comment: Select Simulator -> Goto Hardware -> Keyboard -> Tick Connect Hardware Keyboard

Comment: @the4kman My hardwar keyboard is connected, yes

Comment: Can you deploy on real device, I had similar issue on table view separator lines not visible on simulator but completely perfect on real device.

Comment: any update? I faced the same issue and I did all the above suggestions and no luck